# How to avoid pop up alert while opening multiple window in onclick function

Tags: wordpress, onclick, window.open

I have following code in wordpress post. When I click on the button, it triggers the pop up alert in Chrome and Firefox. Is there a way around this? So that it opens both sites in separate tabs or windows without triggering popup warning?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Windows</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.open("https://www.skyscanner.com.au", "_self");
  window.open("https://www.kayak.com.au");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Windows</button>
<script>
 function myFunction() {
     window.open("https://www.skyscanner.com.au", "_blank");
     window.top.location.href = "https://www.kayak.com.au";
 }
</script>
```